# Rails create new MVC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I would like to create a model called `models/thing.rb`, a controller called `controllers/things_controller.rb`, and views called `views/things/index.html.erb` and `views/things/hello.html.erb`.

How do I do this from the rails console? I know I have to use `rails generate`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly generate the controller with two actions `index` and `hello`.

`rails g controller things index hello`

This command will generate the controller and the views with `views/things/index.html.erb` and `views/things/hello.html.erb`.

Then generate the model:

`rails g model Thing attribute:type [...]`

If you want to know more about `rails generate` command, you can take a look at [A Guide to The Rails Command Line](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-generate)